# CMD Shortcut with arguments

Tags: windows, cmd, arguments, shortcut

I've Created a shortcut to the "cmd" and i added some arguments to execute 
but the arguments just don't execute this is the shortcut

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe \k "for %i in (A,B,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) do (if exist %i:\File.e x e (%i:\File.exe))"
```

Comment: @Stephan I tried that but it's not working :/

Comment: @Stephan Oh Thanks my bad I was missing something else you are right the /k is the correct way to do that but I was Missing SomeThing else Thanks